# Getting "Forbidden" in API Gateway domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

### Background

I'm trying to get GitHub OAuth but [`https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token` endpoint for creating an OAuth access token does not support CORS requests from Web applications.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42150336/16223122)
In the comment it is said to "use AWS API Gateway to create your own authorization call", and I made an API with `amplify add api`.

### Question

My `API Gateway domain name` in `Endpoint configuration` response with 403 while the URL of API and test running correctly.

- `API Gateway domain name` has patter like "d-56789qwert.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com${MAPPING_PATH}/${API_METHOD}/" (start with `d-`)
- path is set to "test" and my "d-56789qwert.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com${MAPPING_PATH}/${API_METHOD}/" (start with `d-`)
- API URL has pattern "https://54321asdfg.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/staging/items" (without `d-`)
- API added with `amplify add api`, `@aws-amplify/cli version 6.1.0`
- Reponse body is `{"message":"Forbidden"}`, header has

```
x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException
x-apigw-api-id: GXt2RGr8TPEFECT=
```

(without `d-`)

### Current workaround 2021oct06

Work around: use firebase.

### What I did

- Searched Stack Overflow, Youtube, Official Doc, Google. Asked in AWS Discord server.
- Cheked the [Official Document](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/) of `ForbiddenException`

1. I don't have API Authorization(it's NONE);
2. I don't have WAF;
3. I have x-apigw-api-id in the response header;
4. The default endpoint is not disabled.

- Work around: use firebase.
- Wrote [my Dev Blog](https://github.com/Pablion/Pablion/wiki/GitHub-Learning-Note).

Comment: if anyone ends up here ... chances are you might have hit this:

9. On custom domain names page, I select “API mappings → Configure API Mappings”.

https://aws.plainenglish.io/custom-domain-for-aws-api-gateway-86d14e0d6024

i.e. forgot to add api mapping for a custom domain on aws.

Comment: It's too heavy for to turn back to AWS now... I hope someone will test this, any maybe answer+close this question.