# Office Script in Excel 365 failed to fetch for some urls

Tags: typescript, office365, office-scripts

I'm using Office Scripts in Excel 365. Function fetch keeps failed with below error. It's so weird because it doesn't fail with some urls, I test okay with dummyjson (for example: https://dummyjson.com/products/1).

```
Line 13: Failed to fetch
```

You can see codes here

```
async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  
  let url = 'http://ip-api.com/json/24.48.0.1';
  let headers = 
  {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };
  let options = {
    'headers': headers,
    'method': 'GET', 
  }

  await fetch(url, options)
  .then(
    (response) => response.json()  
    ).then(
      (result) => console.log(result)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORS) issues, which could block you from making web requests from the current domain (where Office Scripts is running) to some certain domains (where the target Web API is hosted).

Some Web API services choose to allow CORS but some don't. That's why you are seeing inconsistent behaviors when calling into different APIs.

You can confirm it by looking at the Console tab of the browser DevTools (F12 for Chrome/Edge) when running your script. If there is any error like `Access to fetch at ... from origin ... has been blocked by CORS policy...`, then that could be the case.

If you don't have control over the API service provider to enable CORS on the server side, you'll need to find a way to "bridge" your requests through some sort of middle-tier or proxy service. This is called a "***Fetch Proxy***".

In short, it is a simple web server that passes along your original requests to the target API and sends back the responses to your client-side JavaScript. This could work since there won't be CORS problem between this Fetch Proxy server and the target API (server-to-server communication) and at the same time this Fetch Proxy server is configured to allow CORS from your client-side JavaScript.

You can build and host your own Fetch Proxy server, or you can try some existing ones. If you care about data privacy or performance, you probably want to build and host your own. This [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32167044/6656547) was particularly talking about one of the existing popular Fetch Proxy server implementation ("**CORS Anywhere**").

[This article](https://kennethscoggins.medium.com/how-to-make-a-fetch-proxy-in-javascript-to-avoid-cors-errors-with-apis-2b93c4ed0e78) also has some good explanation on this CORS issue and the Fetch Proxy idea.

Answer (score -1):

It's not unusual to encounter problems with the fetch function in your Office Script, especially when it behaves inconsistently with different URLs.

This is a security measure that restricts web applications from making unauthorized cross-origin requests. If you suspect CORS is the issue, check your browser's developer console for any related error messages. To resolve this, contact the server administrator and request the necessary CORS headers. Ensure that you have a stable internet connection and can access the URL you want to fetch from your browser. If you're using a proxy server, double-check that your proxy settings are correctly configured. Review your code for common mistakes like syntax errors.

Try fetching a different URL to check if the issue is specific to one URL. Attempt the fetch from another device to see if the problem persists. Consider increasing the fetch function's timeout by setting a higher value in the options object. Log error messages to the console for better diagnosis.

For your reference, here's some sample code for fetching data using the fetch function:

```
async function fetchData(url) {
try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
}
```

}

This code defines an async function fetchData that uses the fetch function to retrieve data from a specified URL. If there's an error during the fetch, it will be logged to the console.